# FormulaArray not averaging out all the specified entries

Tags: vba, excel-formula, array-formulas

Table 1:

```
  G             H             I             J              K 
| Lane       | Bowler      | Score        | Score        | Score        |  1
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|  
| Lane 1     |       Thomas|     100      |     100      |     100      |  2
| Lane 2     |      column |     200      |     200      |     100      |  3
| Lane 3     |        Mary |     300      |     300      |     100      |  4
| Lane 1     |        Cool |     150      |     400      |     100      |  5
| Lane 2     |       right |     160      |     500      |     100      |  6
| Lane 9     |       Susan |     170      |     600      |     100      |  7
```

say I want to find the average for each Lane that appeared in table 2 and put them in column O:

Table 2:

```
  N             O
| Lane       | Average     | 1
|:-----------|------------:|
| Lane 1     |             | 2 
| Lane 2     |             | 3 
| Lane 3     |             | 4
```

I would put

> =AVERAGE(IF(N2=$G$2:$G$7, $I$2:$K$7 )) for lane 1  (put this formula on cell "O2")
>
> =AVERAGE(IF(N3=$G$2:$G$7, $I$2:$K$7 )) for Lane 2  ("O3")
>
> =AVERAGE(IF(N4=$G$2:$G$7, $I$2:$K$7 )) for Lane 2  ("O4")

1. My first question is
   What if I want to find the Average of ALL the lane together that appear in table 2. So average of Lane 1, Lane 2 and Lane 3 together (but not other lane, such as lane 9).

My attempt:

> = Average(IF(G2:G7 = N2:N4, I2:K:7)) why doesn't this work?

2. My second question is
   I have done the "average of each individual Lane" using vba:

.

```
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 4
        Cells(i, 15).FormulaArray = "=AVERAGE(IF(RC[-1]=R2C7:R7C7,R2C9:R7C12))"
    Next i
```

.

What if I have done it using vba without the .formula method

```
For Lane 1 only:
pseudo code:


Loop from G2 to G7
If cell (N1) = Gx then      //x: 2 to 7
   Sum = Sum + Ix + Jx + Kx
}
Average = Sum/totalEntries
```

Would this be slower than if I were to use the build in .formula? is there a advanage to doing it this way instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***The answer to the first question about why this `FormulaArray`***

> `= Average(IF(G2:G7 = N2:N4, I2:K7))` doesn't work?

Is implicit on how this other `FormulaArray` works:

```
= AVERAGE( IF( $G$7:$G$12 = $N7, $I$7:$K$12 ) )
```

Let’s see how each part of this “single-cell formula array” works:

- 1st part: `$G$7:$G$12 = $N7`

The first part of the formula generates an array with the records from range `$G$7:$G$12` complying with the condition `= $N7`. *Fig. 1 shows the first part of the `FormulaArray` in as a “multi-cell formula array”.*

[image]

- 2nd Part: `$I$7:$K$12`

The result of the first part is applied to the second part to obtain the range of scores complying with the condition `= $N7` *(see Fig. 2)*

[image]

- 3rd part: `AVERAGE`

Finally the last part of the formula calculates the average of the scores complying with the condition `= $N7`

Now let’s try to apply the same analysis to the formula:

`= AVERAGE( IF( G2:G7 = N2:N4, I2:K7 ) )`

Unfortunately, we cannot go beyond the first part `G2:G7 = N2:N4` as it fails trying to compare two arrays of different dimensions thus resulting in `#N/A` *(see Fig. 3)*

[image]

However, even if the arrays have same dimension the result would not have shown the duplicated values, as the members are compared one to one *(see Fig. 4)*

[image]

**To obtain the average for Lanes 1 to 3 use this `FormulaArray`**

```
=AVERAGE( IF(
( $G$7:$G$12 = $N7 ) + ( $G$7:$G$12 = $N8 ) + ( $G$7:$G$12 = $N9 ),
 $I$7:$K$12 ) )
```

It generates an array with the records complying with the conditions `= $N7` + `= $N8` + `= $N9` *(`+` equivalent to operator `OR`)*

[image]

***As regards the second question:***

Performance is intrinsically associated to maintenance and efficiency.

The sample procedure just enters a formula which is hard coded and only works for this particular case, for example:

- If needed to change the formulas to expand the ranges, the macro has to be updated, it may still have to change the formula but no need to open the VBA editor.
- If any of the columns before column `G` get deleted as it becomes obsolete, the macro needs to be updated, while the formulas will not require any maintenance as they are automatically updated.

***In reference to the macro without the `.Formula` method***

I found this redundant, as it’s like writing an algorithm to do something that can be done efficiently and accurately with an existing function, as such a macro will not bring anything that's it's not there actually.

I'll consider the advantage of writing such a procedure in a situation in which the workbook is very large and it heavily uses resource significantly slowing down the performance of the workbook, however the advantages to be delivered by the procedure will not reside and just writing the formulas but it must calculate the results and enter the values resulting from the formulas instead of the formulas thus making the workbook light, fast and smooth to the end user.

Comment: This is prefect!!! exactly what I am looking for. I really appreciate all the details and explanation, I didn't ask for it but I actually did want an explanation on how arrayformula work in the background, so Thankyou so much!! Once I have enough rep I will upvote for sure. I learned a lot from this post, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

To get the average of them all, just use

```
=AVERAGE(I2:K7)
```

As to the VBA, as it is all done on the same lines, could you just use

```
For i = 2 To 7
    Cells(i,"O").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(i,"I"),Cells(i,"K")))
Next i
```

Comment: oh but if i do that it will be average of not just lane 1 -3 but also other lane#. I want the average of all the lane in table 2 that appears in table 1.

As for the VBA part, I already done it, and it works. But my question was is there a difference between using .formulaArray (which I showed there) vs the pseudo code method I showed in question. Obviously formulaArray require less code but is it also faster?

Comment: That depends upon the context. With the data that you show, you will not be able to notice any difference. In that case, it is possible FormulaArray would be slower as it needs for Excel to recalculate, 3 times, rather than the number of summing statements. If there was a MUCH larger dataset, that disadvantage might reduce. But regardless of performance which you won't notice, if my solution was always going to be Excel based, I would opt for the FormulaArray solution, use the built-in capability where possible.

Comment: Thanks! that cleared it up for me. But if performance wise there is no advantage to using the build-in formulaArray, is there a reason why you would prefer it? Or it is just a preference and more professional? or Could it be that when you use formulaArray, when a person open the worksheet they would still be able to understand how the numbers got there cause the formulaArray put in the actual formula in worksheet. Thanks again.

also is my question 1 possible? I feel like if someone can answer me it would really help me get a better understand on excel

Comment: I didn't say no performance, just that I think any advantage either way would be very slight. I guess it is my preference, but I like to think it is more professional :-). My rationale is that if the Excel team has built something already and it does what I want, it makes sense to use it because it is likely to be more efficient than anything that I write, it takes les thinking in working out an algorithm, and it is probably easier to read.

As regards your formula, I did have a quick go at it and failed, but if I can get some time tomorrow I will take another crack.

Comment: o yeah I understand the performance part I just meant if the advantage is only slightly diff then..etc etc. Anyways thank you so much for your help, really appricate it. When I have enough rep I will be able to upvote your reply